# Cloning vs imaging in ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, clone, cloning

Currently I am working on **Ubuntu system**. Now I have to create a backup on the other hard drive, such that I can replicate/install my whole system on the another system.

So I have following drives.

- What is actual difference between clone and imagining.
- I need to replicate all installed softwares/packages into it(For example I have installed ruby on it). So what is the best way for doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Imaging**

Imaging a drive is generally for back-up purposes. The best way to use the computer imaging process would be to take an image of a healthy computer, copy that image file and put it in a safe place, then set up an incremental backup on the original image.

That way when there is a problem with the incremental backup you can always restore to a working state up to the last know safe increment.

**Cloning**

Cloning a drive actually clones the entire contents of the drive to another drive or partition (and does not create an image file).

- clone a hard drive to upgrade to a larger one.
- clone contents of a failing drive to a new one.

> I need to replicate all installed softwares/packages into it(For example I have installed ruby on it). So what is the best way for doing it.

---

- if you want to backup your system but not use it: image it.
- if you want to use that other version (to replace the old one): clone it.

Comment: So as per your suggestion I have to go for `cloning process` right?

Comment: Technically you could use both but cloning is intended for what you want to do so yes I would clone ;)